# How to update the layout(main activity) and load that updated layout every time user opens the app

Tags: android, android-layout

Let's assume there is only one ViewGroup(may be linear layout) in main activity with no child.

If I inflate an view and attach that linear layout as root, then that view is visible on screen.

If we close the app and reopen it, then everything starts from first, like there will be no view on screen.

How can we **save that layout** after adding view, so that we can just use setContentView(view)

**rather than inflating the view every time** ?

I have no idea how to do that.

Comment: There's no simple way to do this.  You need to store the data for the logic that recreates the views.

Comment: Any suggestions on how to proceed, like what to learn or something like youtube tuts or any........

Comment: I'd look at the official [data storage training](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage) and more specifically at [SharedPreferences](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences).

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `recreate()` method to create layout every time